# What is a proper way to debug airflow initalization using docker-compose?

Tags: debugging, docker-compose, airflow

I am running Apache Airflow using docker-compose (below docker-compose.yml that I am using) and can't get debug information in case of any errors.

If any error occurs i.e. some requirements can't be installed (see docker-compose.yml below) I don't see any DAGS in a webserver.

I am using the command `docker-compose up -d` and I tried `docker-compose --verbose up -d` but it doesn't produce any meaningful outcome.

What is a proper way to debug those issues during day-to-day development?

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    ...
  init:
    ...
  webserver:
    ...
  scheduler:
    ...
    command: ["-c", "pip install -r /opt/airflow/env/requirements.txt && airflow scheduler"]
  volumes:
  logs:
```

Comment: You can follow the logs from your services with  `docker-compose logs -f`. Are errors not being logged?

Comment: You're right ... there are and I believe for quick development needs is enough - thanks!